# Which different about cpu-intensive vs data-intensive

Tags: node.js

I have some question about [The_Small_K](https://www.crazyengineers.com/threads/what-is-the-difference-between-data-intensive-and-cpu-intensive-computing.88107/) question with content

I was going through node js tutorial and in between i land to a sentence "node js is a better choice if you want to develop a data-intensive application". I googled it but i didn't get a satisfactory answer.

Can anyone explain what are the basic differences between data-intensive computing and cpu-intensive application ?

Why Node.js good for Data-intensive ?

Thank you.

Comment: Node is asynchronous, so you can load data from disk, write data to disk, read from / save to a database, etc. without blocking the execution of a program.  You can carry on and do (many) more things while all of your I/O operations are being executed.  However, it's inherently single-threaded, so if you have an 8- (or 16-, 32-) core processor, one Node process can only take advantage of one processor.  So, your single node app can come close to saturating your system I/O while only using a fraction of your available CPU resources.

Comment: So. Node.js better for change rate data (change rate is a case of data-intensive). With CPU-intensive we must use a lot of core processors. Node.js not good for them.

Comment: You can try to write an application that runs multiple instances of itself, and even uses inter-process communication methods to coordinate tasks, but the complexity of a distributed application like this is pretty high in Node, and it's only suitable for some applications.  You can max out processors with Node, but it's difficult.